# Utility theory approach in decision making for Gaussian variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, modeling, econometrics, decision-theory

Consider the following problem:-

[image]

In nutshell there are 3 decisions $d_1,d_2,d_3$ and 3 effects $S_1,S_2,S_3$ after the decision has been made. Each effect can occur with a given probability. In normal approach we calculate the expected gain for each decision like for decision $d_1$, we have $30000*0.3+20000*0.5-50000*0.2$. Utility theory is considered a better way of finding the optimal decision. For utility approach we have a utility function, $U(.)$ using which we calculate the expected value. Assume a risk-averse concave utility function is chosen like $\log(x)$. The second matrix in the figure shows the effect of applying one such utility function to the first matrix. Then again expected utility gain is calculated similarly like: $9.5*0.3+9*0.5+0*0.2$.

But if suppose each of the 9 numbers in the first matrix are replaced by Gaussian variables $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and are no more deterministic scalars, how would utility theory be applied then? Else which other theory is available that will help me make decisions effectively in such cases. Basically i am saying that the gains for any decision-effect pair are uncertain and the associated statistics is available.

I am looking to obtain an exhaustive list of different approaches that mathematicians have developed to tackle such problems. If explaining method here is too lengthy then please cite the paper which explains it from scratch.

A naive approach that I can think of is that replace the Gaussian variables with the mean $\mu$ and this then reduces to the original problem. But I want to make use of standard deviation information available and the fact that the gains are uncertain. Incorporating some kind of risk measure like $CVaR_\lambda$ maybe? What i mean is replace the Gaussian variables with a better scalar value like $\alpha\,\mu+(1-\alpha)\,CVaR_\lambda$ where $\alpha \in [0,1]$.